# Joining three tables and filtering data with CodeIgniter ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have the following three tables

```
+----------+ +--------+ +-------------+
| adv      | | member | | removed_adv |
+==========+ +========+ +=============+
| id       | | id     | | id          |
| group    | | group  | | adv_id      |
| category | | email  | | member_id   |
| title    | | pw     | +-------------+
| path     | +--------+
| duration |
+----------+
```

What I am trying to do is to get all the data from table *adv*, where the *member* table's *group* is equal to the  *adv* table's *group*. If the *member* table's *id* is equal to the _removed_adv_ table's _member_id_, that data should be removed from the result set.

I am using CodeIgniter's [Active Record](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Could someone please help me? I really don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select * from adv join member 
on adv.group=member.group
where member.id not in (select member_id from removed_adv)
```

For CodeIgniter:

```
$removed = // get removed records member_id to here;

$CI->db->select('ad');
$CI->db->from('adv ad');
$CI->db->join('mem m', 'ad.group=mem.group', 'left');
$CI->db->where_not_in('mem.id', $removed);
$query = $CI->db->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer could you please tell me how to do this with codeigniter's active records